# Rooted Models in Modal Logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm working through Blackburn *et al.*'s monograph *Modal Logic* and have a hard time grasping exactly what the authors mean by a rooted model.

First some definitions, which for simplicity's sake will be given for the case of the basic modal language (just one diamond). Model $\mathcal{M} =(W, R , V)$ is a *generated submodel* of model $\mathcal{M'} =(W', R', V')$, if (1)$~\mathcal{M}$ is a submodel of $\mathcal{M'}$, that is 
\begin{equation*}
W \subseteq W', R = R' \cap W^2, V(p)= V'(p) \cap W,
\end{equation*}

for all atoms $p$ and (2)$~W$ is upwards closed under $R'$, that is

\begin{equation*}
w \in W \wedge R'wv \Rightarrow v \in W
\end{equation*}

According to the book, for every model $\mathcal{M}$ and every non-empty $X \subseteq W$ there exists the *submodel generated by $X$*, i.e. the smallest generated submodel of $\mathcal{M}$ whose domain extends $X$. For $X$ a singleton this is called a *rooted submodel* of $\mathcal{M}$.

I initially thought that for given $\mathcal{M}$ and subset $X$ the submodel generated by $X$ is the intersection of all the generated submodels of $M$ extending $X$ and the corresponding proof worked quite smoothly. But as I understand the authors, the carrier of a rooted submodel of $\mathcal{M}$ is the set $\{y \in W: x R y \}$, where $x$ is the singleton's member. However I seem unable to prove that the carrier of the intersection model I constructed is identical to that set. So in the end I'm not sure whether my intersection construction goes wrong somewhere or whether I simply do not understand its properties in enough detail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to specify more bibliographical details of/link the resource you're referring to; there are several works on modal logic around by that author. Do you mean https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanbenthem/hml-blackburnvanbenthem.pdf?

Comment: The work I referred to is this:  Blackburn, Patrick, Maarten de Rijke, and Yde Venema: Modal Logic, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the intersection of all the generated submodels" -- given that models are triples $(W, R, V)$, how exactly do you define intersection between them?

Informally speaking, the submodel $M$ of $M'$ generated by $X$ means we pick out some points $x$ -- these are the set $X$ -- as starting points, follow through all the points $y$ that can be reached in finitely many steps from any of the starting points $x$, until every path starting from one of the members of $X$ is walked through. Everything that none of the starting points $x \in X$ can transitively reach is cut out. The thereby obtained graph with its points and relations is the generated submodel.
In the general case for $|X|$ arbitrary, this yields the carrier set $W = \{y \in W': xR'y, \text{for } x \in X\}$. (Mind the prime on $W$ an $R$ in the defintions; we construct the submodel $M$ by restricting on $M'$, otherwise the definition becomes circular.)
In the case where $X$ is a singleton $\{x\}$, all points $y$ reachable from one of the starting points $X$ are reachable from $x$. $x$ is thus the root of the graph, and the carrier is $\{y \in W': xR'y\}$.

Comment: Thanks. By the intersection of a family of models $(M_i)_{i \in I}$ I mean the structure $(W, R, V)$ such that $W = \bigcap W_i, R = \bigcap R_i, V(p) = \bigcap V_i(p)$ My question is: Is the intersection of all generated submodels of some model $M$ which extend $X \subseteq W$ the submodel generated by $X$? If yes, how can this be proved?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by "a model which extends $X$"; is there a formal definition I'm not familiar with? 1) In case you mean "all models with $W$ such that $W \supseteq X$", i.e. all models whose worlds are supersets of $X$, the identity of the two formulations would seem trivial: Extending $X$ to larger sets, then taking the elements that all those sets have in common, just takes one back to $X$ again: $\bigcap \{Y: Y \supseteq X\} = X$. Analogous for $R$ and $V$, so the model intersection would be equivalent as well. So here the answer would be "yes".

Comment: 2) If by "extends $X$" you mean "all models which have $X$ as the domain of possible worlds, and $R$ and $V$ defined arbitrarily", then intersecting the $R$ and $V$ obeying the definition of the generated submodel with other arbitrary $R$ and $V$ might kick out some elements that are supposed to be part of the generated submodel, so in this case the answer would be no. Or do you mean something even different?

Comment: My question concerned the second reading of the phrase. Thanks for the good answer!

Comment: You are welcome.